# Why can't I change video width in CSS?

Tags: css

[In HTML Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Udqx.png)  [In CSS Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwHc2.png)I want to change video's width but I can't change.  I cannot also change in html too. Please someone help me. Here is my code

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" width="290">
    <source src="img/retakevalorant.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

#myVideo{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle with a live example?

Comment: Probably to do with the component that the video is inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `video` tag inside a `container` and then define the desired dimensions for the `container`. The video inside the container will resize itself to fit the container.

I added some padding and a yellow background to the `container` so that it's easier to understand what is happening.

```css
.videoContainer {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;   
    padding: 15px;
    background: yellow;
}

#myVideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoContainer">
    <video autoplay loop controls muted id="myVideo">
      <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to wrap any CSS in style tags, like the following:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo" width="290">
  <source src="img/retakevalorant.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<style>
#myVideo{
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
</style>
```

An alternative to the above is to use a seperate file, which looks cleaner and is easier to maintain. I suggest reading up more on it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

Comment: Thanks your reply. That code is a part of my code, here is the complete code:

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will resolve the aspect ratio problem.

HTML:

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
<source src="img/retakevalorant.mp4" type="video/MP4">
</video>`
```

CSS:

```
<style>    
#myVideo {
         width: 100%;
         height: 600px;
         object-fit: cover;
         z-index: -100;}`
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution but it still cannot work for me :-(

Comment: put your video inside the container and change the size of container as you require.

Comment: Ok I will try it...

Answer (score 0):

Try to place your video inside a container and change the container size as you like. I have created a container and placed the video inside the container. you can copy this code and replace the source file to try this.

```
<style>

.videoContainer {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;   
}

#myVideo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
</style>

<div class="videoContainer">
    <video autoplay loop controls muted id="myVideo">
      <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</div>
```